# Trailing return types, decltype and const-ness

Tags: c++, c++11, const-correctness, decltype, trailing-return-type

I was merily experimenting with the new trailing return types, where I hit a problem with this (simplified) code

```
#include <list>

class MyContainer{
  std::list<int> ints;

  auto begin( ) -> decltype(ints.begin())
  {
    return ints.begin();
  }

  auto begin( ) const -> decltype(ints.begin())
  {
    return ints.begin();
  }
};
```

Ignore the fact of how pointless this code is. The important part is the compiler error generated when using GCC 4.6.1 (with `-std=c++0x` flag):

```
In member function 'std::list<int>::iterator MyContainer::begin() const':
error: could not convert '((const MyContainer*)this)->MyContainer::ints.std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>, std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_List_const_iterator<int>]()' from 'std::list<int>::const_iterator {aka std::_List_const_iterator<int>}' to 'std::list<int>::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<int>}'
```

In case you're not of fan of error involving templates, the short story is that in the body of the `const` version of `MyContainer::begin`, the expression `ints.begin()` returns a value of type `std::list<int>::const_iterator` (since `ints` is `const` in such a context). However, `decltype(ints.begin())` produces the type `std::list<int>::iterator`, i.e. `decltype` *ignores* the `const` qualifier of the `begin` method when deciding the type of the expression. Unsurprisingly, a conflict in types is the result.

This seems to me to be a bug in the GCC compiler. It would only make sense for `decltype` to honor the `const` qualifier and produce the `const_iterator` type. Can anyone confirm or deny (maybe even explain) this? Maybe I am overlooking something in the mechanics of `decltype`, but this looks like a pretty straightforward  scenario.

Note: as far as I can tell, the same behaviour holds not only for `std::list<int>`, but for any type with member functions overloaded on `const`-ness which return incompatible types.

Comment: Compiles without error with recent snapshot of gcc 4.7.0. Until then, I guess you're stuck with `ints.cbegin()`

Comment: Of course, in such a trivial case this was not serious obstacle, but it's important for gcc to get it right for all the non-trivial cases (I also wanted to make sure that *I* got it right - I have no desire to use features I don't understand).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct, this is a bug. According to N3291, section 5.1.1, paragraph 3:

> If a declaration declares a member function or member function template of a class X, the expression this is a prvalue of type “pointer to cv-qualiﬁer-seq X” between the optional cv-qualifer-seq and the end of the function-deﬁnition, member-declarator, or declarator. It shall not appear before the optional cv-qualiﬁer-seq and it shall not appear within the declaration of a static member function (although its type and value category are deﬁned within a static member function as they are within a non-static member function). [Note: this is because declaration matching does not occur until the complete declarator is known. —end note ] Unlike the object expression in other contexts, *this is not required to be of complete type for purposes of class member access (5.2.5) outside the member function body. [Note: only class members declared prior to the declaration are visible. —end note ]

But this was a recent change between the last working draft and N3291. So GCC was right less than 6 months ago; that's the danger of writing code to a moving specification.

Comment: That was part of my thoughts, as I remembered some discussion about the last draft and using `this` in a trailing return type, but I wasn't sure if any of the proposals there were actually accepted. Thank you for the well-referenced answer. Thankfully (according to Cubby's comment), GCC appears to be well on top of this, as version 4.7 already addresses this change.