# How to convert C++ macros to typedefs?

Tags: c++, c, port, typedef, c-preprocessor

Is there is a `typedef` equivalent to:

```
#define HashTabOf(i)    htab[i]
```

and

```
#define MAXCODE(n_bits) (((code_int) 1 << (n_bits)) - 1)
```

?

The code is in the process of being ported from **C** to C++.

Comment: Neither of these is defining a type, so why would there be a `typedef` for them?

Comment: im not sure :( im really confused. would it be better to convert them to a function ? or is that completely wrong?

Comment: Function is completely right.

Answer (score 4):

Not typedef, but the c++ way is:

```
template <typename T>
inline T &HashTabOf(size_t i)
{
    return htab[i];
}
```

and

```
inline size_t MAXCODE(size_t n_bits)
{
    return (1 << n_bits) - 1;
}
```

Comment: Ok that didn't seem to work. Im not aloud to use templates in this task but is there a function i can replace it with

Comment: The first one could be annoying, because the compiler can't automatically deduce the template argument.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Which is why I proposed another solution. C++11 is awesome.

Comment: Why would you need a `template` here? `decltype(htab[i])` is the same for any valid index `i`.

Answer (score 3):

I would implement @Dani's template solution as:

```
inline auto & HashTabOf(size_t i) -> decltype(htab[0])
{
    return htab[i];
}
```

It is valid only in C++11. It uses a feature called [trailing-return-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255379/trailing-return-types-decltype-and-const-ness) introduced by C++11.

The good thing about this solution is that it is not a template anymore. You don't need to mention `T` when you use it, while in @Dani's solution you have to mention `T` as well:

```
auto item = HashTabOf<Type>(4); //Dani's solution 
auto item = HashTabOf(4);       //My solution
```

---

And yes, you can simply write this:

```
inline int & HashofTable(size_t i)
{ 
   return htab[i]; 
}
```

Also, why don't you use `htab[i]` directly?

Comment: sorry guys but this template stuff isnt working for me.
is there a simple way to do this i was hoping for a more...

int HashofTable(i){
    return htab[i];
}

Comment: @DanielDC: If you're not allowed to use template, that is one thing, but saying *"this template stuff isn't working"* is another. Also, this solution is NOT using template. It is a non-template solution.

Comment: I don't really know what templates are at this point so don't take it to heart.